# Conditional dateadd in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that receives 3 parameters:

```
@startdate  = '2017-01-01'
@interval   = 'DD'
@duration   = 5
```

What I need to do is output a new date, based on the above. A dateadd does not work, courtesy of that @interval not being correct.

```
select dateadd(@interval, @duration, @startdate)
```

> Invalid parameter 1 specified for dateadd.

Can anyone steer me right?

Comment: There are just a few variations, so you could do:  `CASE @interval WHEN 'DD' THEN DATEADD(DD...` By the way you'll be able to control input values.

Comment: You can't use parameters like that. You would have to use dynamic sql or a case expression that covers all the options. And really you should avoid using those shortcuts. Why not spell out Day so you don't have to remember the magic codes? https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to need a `CASE` as the arguments cannot be provided dynamically:

```
select case @interval
  when 'dd' then DATEADD(dd, @duration, @startdate)
  when 'mm' then DATEADD(mm, @duration, @startdate)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
select case @interval
  when 'yy' then DateAdd(Year, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'qq' then DateAdd(Quarter, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'mm' then DateAdd(Month, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'wk' then DateAdd(WeeK, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'dd' then DateAdd(Day, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'hh' then DateAdd(Hour, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'mi' then DateAdd(Minute, @duration, @startdate) 
  when 'ss' then DateAdd(Second, @duration, @startdate)
else null
end
```

Answer (score 4):

One method is to use dynamic SQL.  Another is a giant `case` statement.  Something like:

```
declare @endDate date;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'select @endDate = dateadd(@interval, @duration, @startdate)';
set @sql = replace(@sql, '@interval', @interval);

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@duration int, @startdate date, @endDate date output',
                   @duration = @duration, @startdate = @startdate,
                   @endDate = @endDate output;
```

The problem is that the first argument is a keyword, not a string.  So, it cannot be passed in as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks G, adding this to my knowledge bank, but not used in this case